# suddenly can't install packages to pycharm? (Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock error?)

Tags: python, pycharm, package, pipenv

Error is posted here as pastebin, it's very long

```
'''https://pastebin.com/8ssgGNdL'''
```

(edit paste bin expired)
https://pastebin.com/BRuPeifp

I've since tried installing packages using pip3 and still get similar results. I haven't changed anything since the last time I installed 'requests'

I'm sorry if i'm asking an annoying question. I've googled similar questions but nothing seems to help. If anyone can point me in the right place to look and solve this for my self I will be very grateful.

Comment: Btw your link doesn't work I had to copy and paste it into the url bar.

Comment: What's the output of the command `pip3 --version`?

Comment: pip 20.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8) @HampusLarsson

Comment: @RIPPLR fixed the pastebin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**~ Solved ~**

pygame doesn't work with python3.8 so I had to use:

```
pipenv install pygame==2.0.0.dev6
```

when testing by trying to install other packages such as requests, I was met with the same error. This error was infact the error for pygame repeating itself (I don't understand why)

Answer (score 1):

The error states:

> fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found

and

> For help with compilation see:', 'https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile'

It looks like one or more of the SDL dependencies is missing.

Have you installed SDL dependencies mentioned on that page using HomeBrew?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's crashing while installing PyGame. According the PyGame's [Getting Started](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted#Mac%20installation) page there seems to be some issues with newer version of OS X.

Quoting from the page:

> If your examples aren't running and you are using a recent version of
> Mac OS X; try this line to install pygame instead:
>
> python3 -m pip install -U pygame==2.0.0.dev6 --user

Also looking over the Internet, the problem might be because of `Python3.8` itself, and therefore requiring a newer version to resolve the issue.